# Created an object but its still null in objective-c, iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my function:

```
- (void) function{
    if (_app.error == nil) {  
        for (Window *window in _app.windows) {
            NSLog(@"test.");
        }

    }
    else {  
        NSLog(@"%@",[_app.error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Instead of going into the for loop and printing out "test.", its giving me "(null)" from the else statement. What am I doing wrong?

```
+ (App *)loadApp {

NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath:FALSE];
NSData *xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSError *error;
GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData options:0 error:&error];

App *app = [[App alloc] init];

if (doc == nil) app.error = error;

...etc
```

Comment: Show the code that initialized `_app.error`.

Answer (score 1):

You've simply got your logic back-to-front; you want to continue if there is **no** error (`_app.error == nil`):

```
- (void) function{
    if (_app.error == nil) {      // NOT !=
        for (Window *window in _app.windows) {
            NSLog(@"test.");
        }

    }
    else {  
        NSLog(@"%@",[_app.error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that is my code. But it never comes into the for loop.

Comment: @user1345821 Sorry I don't understand.  What is your code?

Comment: I edited my code now, my code is like you said, but the NSLog with "test." doesn't print out. So it never gets into the for loop

Comment: What do you mean? I changed my code for testing purposes and I posted the wrong code here...

Comment: What does the error say then? (What does that NSLog() print?)